# How to fix up reversed RSS output?

Tags: php, rss

I hope someone can help me with matter- my RSS feed works fine and returns the correct data, however the order of the entries is reversed in date. (It shows the oldest entries at the top, and newest at the bottom).

From my understanding - when using RSS - it should be the other way around. New items (by date) should appear at the top and old at the bottom. Can anyone point me into the right direction how to make it so? Here is my rsslib.php:

https://pastebin.com/raw/8DccUnUj

Could this part be responsible for it?

```
function mySort($a, $b){
    global $RSS_Content;
    return strcmp($RSS_Content[$a]['date'], $RSS_Content[$b]['date']);
}
```

Comment: `strcmp` is not good for dates. Aside: any reason why you are using a global var in your sort handler? `$a` and `$b` are references to elements of the array you pass to `uksort()`.

Comment: Then, what should I use instead of `strcmp`? 
Unfortunately, I am not a developer so I don't know. I had this entire code ordered by a freelance developer and he kind of just ghosted out on me, hence why I am here now. :-(

Comment: `From my understanding - when using RSS - it should be the other way around. New items (by date) should appear at the top and old at the bottom.` Why sort at all given this statement you made? Did you try it without sorting?

Comment: Thanks! This helped me get one step closer but also put me one back elsewhere. I removed this function snipped: 
`function mySort($a, $b){
    global $RSS_Content;
    return strcmp($RSS_Content[$a]['date'], $RSS_Content[$b]['date']);
}`
now the feed items show in the correct order. However, $a and $b return separate boards (I am fetching data from two different forum categories), so upon removing this code entirely, it only displays topics from board $a.  The real issue lies - as you said - in `strcmp`, What else could I use than that that maintains correct sorting but shows both boards?